# Android Tiramisu Privacy Sandbox Preview emulator does not start

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-tiramisu

I'm interested in trying out the SDK Runtime environment that is going to be a major change among the advertising SDKs coming soon.

I wanted to start the emulator with this, but when trying to do this I get stuck on a black screen.
The logs I receive are as follows:

```
INFO    | Android emulator version 31.2.10.0 (build_id 8420304) (CL:N/A)
WARNING | unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator.
```

I have followed the instructions in described here: https://developer.android.com/design-for-safety/privacy-sandbox/setup, but no luck - cannot see any newer version of `emulator`.

How can I get this system image to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I wasn't running the newest version of the `emulator` tool indeed.

I needed to use Android Studio Preview to be able to see a new update available to this tool, then I updated to `31.3.7`.

From now on I'm able to run the Tiramisu Privacy Sandbox Preview emulator, although the same warning about updating is being logged.